# How to easily apply Crypto++ hash functions?

Tags: c++, windows, md5, sha1, crypto++

Can someone help me how can I easily use hash functions from Crypto++ library?
I tried used these codes for SHA1 and MD5. I have many errors on line where is `StringSink`. The errors are like:

```
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)'
```

Thanks for help.

```
 // SHA
CryptoPP::SHA1 sha1;
std::string source = "Hello";
std::string hash = "";
CryptoPP::StringSource(source, true, new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha1, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hash))));
std::cout << hash;

// MD5
CryptoPP::MD5 hash;
byte digest[ CryptoPP::MD5::DIGESTSIZE ];
std::string message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) message.c_str(), message.length() );

CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
std::string output;
encoder.Attach( new CryptoPP::StringSink( output ) );
encoder.Put( digest, sizeof(digest) );
encoder.MessageEnd();

std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have many errors on line where is StringSink

This line with the `StringSink` looks OK to me. You should provide the exact error  that you are encountering.

---

> Error on line with StringSink is: undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)'

Based on the additional information you provided, see [Building and linking test code for Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872129/building-and-linking-test-code-for-crypto)

---

> How use easily apply Crypto++ hash functions?

Below is from the Crypto++ wiki on the [ChannelSwitch](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ChannelSwitch) class. Since you want MD5, you need to `#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1`, and then `#include <cryptopp/md5.h>`. After that, you can find MD5 in `Weak::MD5`.

```
string message = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country";
if(argc == 2 && argv[1] != NULL)
    message = string(argv[1]);

string s1, s2, s3, s4;
SHA1 sha1; SHA224 sha224; SHA256 sha256; SHA512 sha512;

HashFilter f1(sha1, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s1)));
HashFilter f2(sha224, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s2)));
HashFilter f3(sha256, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s3)));
HashFilter f4(sha512, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(s4)));

ChannelSwitch cs;
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f1);
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f2);
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f3);
cs.AddDefaultRoute(f4);

StringSource ss(message, true /*pumpAll*/, new Redirector(cs));

cout << Message: " << message << endl;
cout << "SHA-1: " << s1 << endl;
cout << "SHA-224: " << s2 << endl;
cout << "SHA-256: " << s3 << endl;
cout << "SHA-512: " << s4 << endl;
```

A run of the program produces the results shown below:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe password
Message: password
SHA-1: 5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8
SHA-224: D63DC919E201D7BC4C825630D2CF25FDC93D4B2F0D46706D29038D01
SHA-256: 5E884898DA28047151D0E56F8DC6292773603D0D6AABBDD62A11EF721D1542D8
SHA-512: B109F3BBBC244EB82441917ED06D618B9008DD09B3BEFD1B5E07394C706A8BB9
         80B1D7785E5976EC049B46DF5F1326AF5A2EA6D103FD07C95385FFAB0CACBC86
```

Comment: Error on line with StringSink is: undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<std::string>::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)'

Comment: Do you have to delete any of those `HexEncoder*` or `StringSink*` heap instances, or do those other classes – those you are stack-allocating in your example code, like e.g. `HashFilter` – manage their lifecycles? Or are there CryptoPP conventions for dealing with these resources? … those learning the library, like myself, would benefit from a hint or two on such things

Comment: @fish2000 - No, no need to delete them because they are a pointer. The object the pointer is attached to owns the pointer. References are different because you manage them. Its an acquired taste :) See the `README.txt` and the part on object ownership. We have a wiki page about it at [Pipelining](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining), but the VM is unreachable at the moment because of problems with the hosting company and upstream provider.

Comment: @jww awesome, thanks for that tip (I had also been thwarted by the unavailable wiki) – but yeah the CryptoPP parts seem to sport a pretty well-designed API in those regards; one doesn’t have to slap a bunch of `unique_ptr`s all over it, it would seem. The entire `cryptest.sh` suite is still running on my end, as soon as that is done it looks like it’ll be a pleasant library to work with, indeed.

Comment: Be careful with `cryptest.sh` because it runs 40 to 50 tests (x2 because its both `cryptest.exe v` and `cryptest.exe tv all`). On a 5th gen i7, it takes 2 1/2 to 3 hours. I regularly test on ARM, and it takes days to run. I recently added `cryptest.sh fast` to skip valgrind and benchmarks. Its a quicker smoke test that completes in about an hour. I also find two clones work best - one to work from, one to run `cryptest.sh` from.

Comment: The API is an acquired taste. It shocks most people, but its gotten better since we made documentation and the wiki priorities. Wei Dai designed it back in the late 1990s, and I'm amazed at how well it has held up. There's a few pain points, but Wei had no way to know some thing 20 years in advance, like memory-hard hashing (the KDFs need a major change at 6.0 to account for the additional security parameters).

Comment: @jww Using ChannelSwitch is it possible to have result as BYTE instead of string ?