# Hash output as BYTE instead of std::string?

Tags: c++, crypto++

My question/problem might be a bit newbie regarding this field, but I cannot find any solution or clear explanation to achieve what I want.

#### The problem

I must store and use the hash values as BYTE instead of STRING because of the size. ( it causes me troubles in other areas )

The function generates an MD5 hash for a file, used on windows OS.

#### Current code

```
std::string MD5Checksum(const path &file)
{
    std::string result;
    try
    {
        CryptoPP::Weak::MD5 md5;

        CryptoPP::HashFilter f5(md5, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(result)));

        CryptoPP::ChannelSwitch cs;
        cs.AddDefaultRoute(f5);

        CryptoPP::FileSource ss(file.string().c_str(), true /*pumpAll*/, new CryptoPP::Redirector(cs));
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception const& exception)
    {
      // 
    }

    return result;
}
```

#### What I tested

```
std::string MD5Checksum(const path &file)
{
    std::string result;
    try
    {
        CryptoPP::Weak::MD5 md5;

        CryptoPP::HashFilter f5(md5, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(result)));

        CryptoPP::ChannelSwitch cs;
        cs.AddDefaultRoute(f5);

        CryptoPP::FileSource ss(file.string().c_str(), true /*pumpAll*/, new CryptoPP::Redirector(cs));
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception const& exception)
    {
        //
    }

    string decoded;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(result, true /*pumpAll*/, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decoded));
    const BYTE* data = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(decoded.data());
    printf(L"sizeof result: %d, sizeof data: %d"), sizeof(result), sizeof(data));

    return result;
}
```

This seems to achieve the desired result, because the size of result string is 40 and the size of data is 8 which is a massive reduction in size for me.

However I do not see this as a good solution and I am pretty sure that there must but an easier and cleaner way of doing this.

Any examples are much appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof` of a pointer is always the size of the pointer *itself*, not whatever it might point to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You got me thinking...

Comment: Furthermore, `sizeof` of an object is the size of the object itself, not whatever data it might wrap (a `std::string` is essentially a pointer to the string data, and the size of the data, plus maybe some internal meta-data for housekeeping).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So my result is false then ? I thought sizeof returns the size of the data...

Comment: The length of a `std::string` is what the `size()` or `length()` member functions returns.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `printf` formats for decimal output of the type `size_t` (which is what `sizeof` results in) is `"%zu"`. Mismatching format specifier and type leads to *undefined behavior*. This is of course solved by using `std::cout` for all your output, where such mistakes can't be made.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for that.

Comment: A byte has eight bits and can represent 256 values. This is almost certainly insufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must store and use the hash values as BYTE instead of STRING because of the size...

You are almost there.

Both `StringSource` and `ArraySink` can handle `byte` arrays. You just need to use alternate constuctors. Also see [`StringSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/StringSource) and [`ArraySink`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySink) on the Crypto++ wiki.

I would modify the code similar to the following. I'm using C++11 so I don't have `std::path`:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "hex.h"

#define CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_NAMESPACE_WEAK 1
#include "md5.h"

#include <iostream>

#if defined(CRYPTOPP_NO_GLOBAL_BYTE)
using CryptoPP::byte;
#endif

bool MD5Checksum(const std::string &file, byte* digest, size_t size)
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    try
    {
        Weak::MD5 md5;
        FileSource(file.c_str(), true /*pumpAll*/,
            new HashFilter(md5, new ArraySink(digest, size)));
    }
    catch (Exception const& exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    std::string filename = (argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "./cryptlib.h");
    byte digest[Weak::MD5::DIGESTSIZE];

    if (MD5Checksum(filename, digest, sizeof(digest)))
    {
        std::cout << "Filename: " << filename << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Digest: ";
        StringSource(digest, sizeof(digest), true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to calculate digest of " << filename << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And then compile. I'm working from the `cryptopp/` directory in my home directory:

```
$ g++ ./test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$
```

And finally:

```
$ ./test.exe
Filename: ./cryptlib.h
Digest: 626047BC8770BE942B26B3AD6CBD3781
```

In the code above, here are the sources and sinks wrapping the byte array:

```
StringSource(digest, sizeof(digest) ...);
ArraySink(digest, size);
```

---

If you were storing into a `std::string` like in [How to easily apply Crypto++ hash functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29467707/608639), here are the sources and sinks wrapping the `std::string`. They are different constructors.

```
std::string digest;
...

StringSource(digest, ...);
StringSink(digest);
```

Comment: Excellent solution... thank you very much. Can I be a bit cheeky and ask if it's the same situation for SHA1 as well ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. All hash functions derive from base class `HashTransformation`. You can swap-in any hash for any other hash. Also see [`MD5`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/MD5),  [`SHA`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SHA), [`BLAKE2`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/BLAKE2) and friends on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: You should probably consider using SHA-256, BLAKE2 or SHA-3. MD5 and SHA-1 are usually considered insecure for new applications. Also thumb through the wiki. I keep it well stocked with sample code. My feelings are, if you have to ask a question then we failed at the documentation.

Comment: I know... but unfortunately the result/size of SHA-256 for example is enormous for me to use, especially when I need to hash 1000+ files...

Comment: And what do you mean you keep it well stocked ? You writing in that wiki ? :O

Comment: I don't know your requirements, but a truncated hash may be useful to you. A truncated hash uses the first N bytes of the digest instead of the entire digest.

Comment: I was just reading about that actually, my requirements are not that complex... but I need this hash as small as possible.

Comment: Can you please post me a proper sample of SHA-256/BLAKE2 with byte output and truncation ? I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @Norbert - Please ask a new question. BLAKE2 and SHA-3 need special treatment. I don't think it should be tacked onto this question. Otherwise, if you are using SHA-256, just use a smaller buffer.